# Emulator's height and width differs from that of real device

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have a android tablet( Samsung gt-P1010 ) whose screen details is as follows,

```
Screen resolution- 600*1024
Density- 240
Screen size- Normal
```

I created an emulator of the same details like above but when I print the Width and Height, it gives 600*961 .Why there is such a big difference ? I am using the following code to get the device details,

```
 DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        screenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        screenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
        screendensity = displaymetrics.densityDpi;
```

In my application I am trying to run a .gif image above the Alphabets for which I am taking margins based on the width and height of the device. Due to the above difference, emulator and real device gives different result. Please anyone tell me whats wrong here.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: that's the status bar ...

Comment: But I have applied Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen theme.

Comment: the bottom bar with the home, back and recent buttons, then

Comment: And also if the device is in Landscape mode , it gives that same size

Comment: Did you create an emulator with the same version of Android like on your real device?

Comment: @synergy: no.Is it a problem then ?

Comment: Maybe yes. Once I was faced with similar problem, I launched my application on the GalaxyTab 2 10.1 with Android 4.0.3 and on the emulator with Android 4.2.2 and noticed small difference in layout: notification area was moved from bottom to top and hight of application's area was changed

Answer (score 0):

`Display metrics` give the screen dimensions including the status bar and excluding the soft keys area. On 2.x devices it will give you the complete screen size but on 4.x devices(which have soft keys) it will exclude the soft key area.

Comment: It may differ the height of the device but what about the width? Will it affect the width too?

Comment: It is supposed to be 600x1024 but when you try to read it using display metrics it excludes the soft key area and you get 600*961 instead. The orientation doesn't matter. The display metrics is returned expecting the default orientation (at least I haven't seen it make a difference). Again this is all from personal observation(over a long time) and I haven't seen any documentation regarding the same.

Comment: This is also true for real devices (I've only tried it on real devices)

Comment: orientation will switch between the values of width and height and might also change them (nexus 4 for example: 1196x768 for horizontal and 768x1184 for vertical). btw , you can use getResources().getDisplayMetrics() instead, which is a bit shorter...

Comment: Well your points make sense to me. If I remove the softkey are from the AVD then can I get the full width of the device ?

Comment: As far as I know you can't hide the softkey (on real devices). If you did, how is the user supposed to close the app?

Comment: No I am talking about the AVD. In real device it shows the exact height and width.

Comment: If the real device has soft keys, it shouldn't show the exact height and width

Comment: Well logcat show 1024*600 width and height for the real device

Comment: Well that's beyond me.. I've tried this on Nexus 4, Galaxy Nexus, Nexus 7 and it always excludes the soft key area.

Comment: @SrikantSahay: I too checked in other devices and as you said it excludes the soft key area but I dont understand why for this device it shows the full width and height.

Comment: I just checked on net. Your device is a tab with physical hard keys upgradable to android 2.3. You should get full width and height (on actual device) at least. http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_p1010_galaxy_tab_wi_fi-pictures-3919.php It doesn't have soft keys so display metrics will give full dimensions of screen.